# Updating Parse Data in UiTableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a tableview that is full of current user data that is stored in parse. I want to be able to click on the cell of the parse data and be able to edit that data in a edit screen (which is just going to be the screen where you save the data from) then be able to save it and it update in the parse class on the cloud. I saw this code on the parse developer website regarding updating objects [Updating Objects Here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-updating-objects)

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"
                     block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @YES;
gameScore[@"score"] = @1338;
[gameScore saveInBackground];
}];
```

But the problem is that in the

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"
                     block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error)
```

Is a query by the specific ObjectId that is stated. How can I change this so that when a user clicks on the tableview cell the query runs by that specific ObjectId in parse so that I can edit the strings associated with the ObjectId. Any tutorials or guidance is really appreciated!

Here is my Tableview.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"rep";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell        style
    self.textKey = @"name";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    //self.objectsPerPage = 10;
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                             name:@"refreshTable"
                                           object:nil];
{
    UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Delete Cannot    Be Undone" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil];
    [Alert show];
}

}
- (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
// Reload the recipes
[self loadObjects];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable

{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"rep"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];



return query;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RepCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name" ];

UILabel *time = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
time.text = [object objectForKey:@"time"];


return cell;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Remove the row from data model
PFObject *objectToDel = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[objectToDel deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {



    UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Item Was Deleted Successfully. Pull Down to Refresh Tab" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil];
    [Alert show];
    [self loadView];

}
 ];
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: You want only current user objectID when click on tableview cell?

Comment: then try [[PFUser currentUser] objectId], it will return object ID in NSString pass to your function.

Comment: Happy to help! @spel

Comment: You already have the object as you're displaying it on the table, so you shouldn't need to query for it again...